# Command binding not working WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a command that is bound to a button in WPF, but for the life of me, I can't get the function to fire.

## XAML

ControlPanelViewModel is the VM I'm working in.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ControlPanel:ControlPanelViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

   <Button x:Name="button" Command="{Binding NavCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

## ControlPanelViewModel.cs

```
    public ControlPanelViewModel()
    {
        NavCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnNav);
    }

 public RelayCommand<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnNav(string destination)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is working");
        switch (destination)
        {
            case "credential":
                CurrentViewModel = _credentialViewModel;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now, avoiding the logic inside OnNav, I'm never seeing my `console.writeline` get called ever. I've been stuck on this for hours. Data context looks fine, setup looks fine. Let me know if RelayCommand class is necessary to view.

Comment: Yes, the RelayCommand class is necessary. It is possible that it will never call OnNav because the command parameter is null

Comment: BTW Did you try to run the app with the debugger and set a breakpoint inside OnNav method?

Comment: @SirRufo: event if the parameter is not set, the command handler will be called... just checked!

Comment: @adPartage How do you know which RelayCommand<T> class the OP is using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be coming from the [`RelayCommand`](https://github.com/adpartage/wpf/blob/master/RelayCommand.cs) Implementation. Does it inherit from `ICommand`? How do you implement `Execute` and `CanExecute`? in your case, `CanExecute` should return `true`